# create PGP key pair from own primes

Tags: python, rsa, pgp

I can easily create a PGP key pair using

```
    gpg --full-generate-key
```

and follow the steps to create an (lets say) 4096 bit RSA key pair

I can export the private and public key into (unencrypted) files

```
    gpg --export-key -a > pub.key
    gpg --export-secret-key -a > priv.key
```

I can also see the internal numbers N, d and e used in the keys pair with

```
    pgpdump -i pub.key
    pgpdump -i priv.key
```

With the python module cryptograpgy i can compute the primes p and q that were originally used to create the keys from the numbers N, e and d seen from pgpdump.
Python code:

```
    import cryptography
    n = ....
    e = ....
    d = ....
    p,q = cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.rsa_recover_prime_factors(n, e, d)
```

But I can only see/compute the numbers N, e, d, p, q, I cannot modify them. I am aware they are not required for using the PGP keys in the usual way, but I would like to **create a PGP key pair with my own set of numbers N, e, d, p, q**. I understand the math but not how to put it into the PGP formatting.

Question: using gpg or python or some other magic, is it possible to create a valid RSA4096 GPG key pair using **numbers N/e/d/p/q of my choice**?

Comment: The answer is obviously yes, you just have to replicate the cryptography library on your own

Comment: I was hoping for a solution with a little less magic......

Comment: This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out around code that you are writing. Your question, instead, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Can someone point me towards a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)